# Yup: Ensure at least one of the elements in an array is valid

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

I have the following schema:

```js
const baseSchema = {
  name: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      lang: Yup.string().required(),
      value: Yup.string()
        .min(2)
        .max(20)
        .required()
    })
  )
};
```

Is there a way to consider the schema valid if at least one of the objects in `name` is valid?

Edit: essentially it has to use `when()`, but what I'm struggling with is to find out how to check the other elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xor` if you want one of them to be required:

```
const baseSchema = {
  name: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      lang: Yup.string().required().allow(""),
      value: Yup.string()
        .min(2)
        .max(20)
        .required().allow("")
    })
  )
};
```

Comment: No, I meant even if the array is [{lang: "en", value: "foo"}, {lang: "", value: ""}], cosider it valid.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you have to allow "" by `.allow("")`

Comment: This would allow `[{lang: "", value: ""}, {lang: "", value: ""}]` to be valid.